# Why does bootstrap stack these scaled elements in columns vertically?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I have a `<div>` element which is given sizes in `in` (it's modeling a postcard, so the dimensions have to match the physical card). For display, I scale these elements down using `transform: scale(0.5);` or similar. This works fine, however when trying to display two of these side by side, bootstrap is stacking the columns on top of one another even though the elements inside should fit side by side in the max width of the column.

I have a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/g5jnfz9u/9/. I would expect this behavior on a mobile device, but even at fullscreen on a high res monitor they're still displayed vertically. I can see when inspecting that the actual `col` element is much wider than the content inside it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your col class divs as following:

I think that because you are scaling your divs this could affect how 'col' works, or the version of bootstrap you are using doesn't support the use of 'col'

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on. An updated example here: https://jsfiddle.net/43ez7c0x/

First: When using the grid classes. `container`, `row`, `col`. It's generally best not to override your own styling as it will interfere with the bootstrap grid system styles.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Second: If you set an item in a col to have a certain width, the grid will attempt to respect that. e.g. if you set 5.14in it will set this as a sort of *minimum* width.

Comment: overrides in the original code were just so I could show where the columns actually are. I'm still not clear why the scaling of the inner box doesn't scale the column. It makes sense that without the scaling the column would be that wide (min width) but I'd think it would also change the width when elements under it are scaled.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is behaviour more similar to *zoom*:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.some-box {
  width: 6.25in;
  height: 4.25in;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: 6.25in 4.25in;
  background-color: black;
}

.scale-down {
  zoom: 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 3px red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="scale-down">
        <div class="some-box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="scale-down">
        <div class="some-box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

> The non-standard zoom CSS property can be used to control the magnification level of an element. transform: scale() should be used instead of this property, if possible. However, **unlike CSS Transforms, zoom affects the layout size of the element.**
>
> — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom